# React-Native Android Virtual Device Menu does not open with Ctrl+M (on Windows using expo SDK build) once an exception is thrown

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, debugging

Oof well, I've been trying to solve this one for a few days.  I've read through all the similar questions related to shortcut keys like CTRL+M Menu not working, but most are addressing the MacOS platform tools PATH issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm quite new to android studio.

**The Issue:**
I'm running React-Native with Expo (w/ the Expo SDK build -- not the bare workflow) and trying to access the **remote JS debugger with Ctrl+M** but when an exception is thrown but the Android Virtual Device does not respond to shortcut keys.  Weirdly, the keyboard shortcuts and menu works *before* any exception is thrown, though of course that is not so helpful.

**What I tried:**

0. In the virtual device settings, I toggled `"Send shortcuts to:" Virtual Device` instead of default `"Send shortcuts to:" Emulator Controls` This caused app to timeout and return a network error
1. I tried adding Android SDK path to environment variables (yea, I'm on windows and as per Expo docs I understand it's only necessary on Mac, but eh I was feeling optimistic).
2. Installed the vs code extension React-Native Tools but when I click Add Configuration, there is no Android device on the list of configurations.
   [image]
3. Tried adding PATH variables to .bash_profile because I'm using Git BASH (even though I'm on Windows and not Mac) and I made sure to use the correct path found in SDK manager.
4. I also tried adding environment variables in System Properties under PATH.  **Previously adb cmd returned 'abd command not found'** But once I added these, I'm now able to successfully run adb from BASH and cmd prompt (I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, yet I still can't access menu to remote JS debug )
5. I've also tried sighing and groveling a bit. That didn't work either.

Running Windows 10, Pixel XL API 30 avd and dependencies are below

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  }
```

Thanks in advance!